# Using Date_Sub to subtract year with Aliases column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli, alias

I have two column `brand` and `date_time` and during select I assign them to aliases. The query below:

```
SELECT brand, 
YEAR(date_time) AS 'year', 
SUM( brand = 'KFC' ) AS kfc
SUM( brand = 'PZH' ) AS pzh, 
SUM( brand = 'SUB' ) AS sub
FROM scan_report
GROUP BY YEAR(date_time)
```

Result to this:

[image]

Now here's the confuse part. How can I use `Date_Sub` function to display data only for the last 5 years. I mean user will enter `2014` and will only display/select record from the last 5 year that means from `2010 to 2014`.

Using `WHERE` such as this gave me empty records:

```
SELECT  
YEAR(date_time) AS 'year', 
SUM( brand = 'KFC' ) AS kfc
SUM( brand = 'PZH' ) AS pzh, 
SUM( brand = 'SUB' ) AS sub
FROM scan_report WHERE DATE_SUB(2014, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
GROUP BY YEAR(date_time)
```

or this

```
FROM scan_report WHERE DATE_SUB(year = 2014, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

Any idea how I can retrieve record from the last 5 years of user input? I prefer to solve this problem with mysql, if no solution is found than I'll go with php. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this simple math in PHP:

```php
$year = 2014; # from $_POST or anywhere else
$from = ($year - 4) . '-01-01 00:00:00';
$to = $year . '-12-31 23:59:59';
```

And then use this 2 variables in query.

```php
$sql = "
    ...
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
    ...
";
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/210283)</kbd>

### UPDATE (calculation in SQL):

If you don't want to calculate in PHP, you can then calculate in MySQL:

```php
$sql = "
    ...
    WHERE 
        date_time BETWEEN CONCAT({$year}-4, '-01-01 00:00:00') AND CONCAT({$year}, '-12-31 23:59:59')
    ...
";
```

### UPDATE (don't care about speed or indexes):

```
$sql = "
    ...
    WHERE 
        YEAR(date_time) AND {$year}-4 AND {$year}
    ...
";
```

Comment: I actually prefer to solve it with mysql and try to avoid PHP (even though it's simple). If no solution is found, I will go with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the predicate in the WHERE clause is returning NULL for every row, so no rows are being returned.

The `DATE_SUB` function takes a DATE expression as the first argument, not an integer. That is, you could specify `'2014-01-01'` as the first argument, rather than `2014`. That would return a non-zero date, which would evaluate to TRUE (in a boolean context) so all rows would be returned.

To include rows that have particular values of `date_time`, you'd need to use a comparison in the predicate (WHERE clause). To return rows with date_time values of '2009-01-01' and later...

```
SELECT YEAR(t.date_time)      AS year
     , SUM( t.brand = 'KFC' ) AS kfc
     , SUM( t.brand = 'PZH' ) AS pzh
     , SUM( t.brand = 'SUB' ) AS sub
  FROM scan_report t 
 WHERE t.date_time >= DATE_SUB('2014-01-01', INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
 GROUP BY YEAR(date_time)
```

Some additional notes: if you need (or want) to escape an identifier (e.g. a column name, because it's a reserved word), enclose the identifier in backtick characters, not single quotes, e.g.

```
SELECT YEAR(`t`.`date_time`)  AS `year`
```

Comment: Thanks it works but have to set it like this to grab records for the last 5 year `WHERE t.date_time >= DATE_SUB( '2014-12-31', INTERVAL 5 YEAR )`. What I don't understand is this `t.date_time` because usually `t` is for table name for example `scan_report.date_time` but somehow you can replace it with something else. Also here `FROM scan_report t`, do you assign `scan_report` to `t` and use it on all column above? Appreciate some explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, `t` is a short alias assigned to the table `scan_report` in the query. We can qualify column references using the short alias, e.g.   `t.date_time` is a reference to the `date_time` column in the `scan_report` table. SQL doesn't require that column references be qualified, but in queries that reference multiple tables, it's a pattern that provides significant benefits. We follow the same pattern in single table queries, for consistency (You could remove the `t` alias and remove the `t.` qualifiers; the query would be the same.)

Comment: Note that we're using a **`>=`** operator (a *greater than or equal to* comparison. If we compare **`date_time>='2009-12-31'`**, that would include date_time values from just December 31st. Nothing invalid SQL-wise with that, but perhaps not what is intended. Personally, I'd avoid using the `DATE_SUB` function, and just specify the value, **`'2009-01-01'`**, or **`'2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 5 YEAR`**, but that doesn't make any difference. (The specification "last five years" is open to interpretation. I'd think we'd want all rows for a year, not just from December 31st.)

Comment: If we don't want to include any rows from 2009, we'd specify **date_time >= `'2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 4 YEAR'`**.  (That's the current year (2014) and the previous *four* years (2010 thru 2013).

Comment: WHERE `t.date_time  >= 2014-01-01 - INTERVAL 4 YEAR` gave me empty result. When I include the single quote at the date I get mysql error. Using `WHERE t.date_time >=2014 -01 -01 - 'INTERVAL 4 YEAR'` gave me result from year 2012 to 2014.

Comment: @sg552: You are missing the single quotes around the date literal, and you have single quotes around `INTERVAL 4 YEAR`. (That is *not* the same as what I showed in my comment. **`'2014-01-01'`** (in single quotes) is a date date literal, but `2014-01-01` (not enclosed in single quotes) evaluates to `NULL` in a date or numeric context. Adding single quotes around `INTERVAL 4 YEAR`, that turns it into a string literal. That evaluates to 0 in numeric context. `NULL+0` is `NULL`, so we don't expect any rows to match. Try what I suggested: **`date_time >= '2014-01-01' - INTERVAL 4 YEAR`**

Comment: If I use this `WHERE t.date_time >= '2012-01-01' - INTERVAL 2 YEAR` I should be getting records from 2010 to 2012 right? but for some reason I'm getting records from 2010 to 2014. I appreciate your reply.